# Why is lazy matching grabbing more than it seems it needs to, here?

Tags: regex, intellij-idea

[image]

I'm searching for `".*?Model"` on the string `"id": "FooModel"`.  Since I'm using lazy matching, I'd expect this to match `"FooModel"`, but it's matching on the whole string instead.  Why is this happening and how do I get what I want?

Comment: Why did you expect it to match the `Foo`? Why didn't you expect it to just match `Model`?

Comment: Matches from the start. `.*` matches everything so the pattern grabs everything.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I think you're right.  How should I change my regex?  From my perspective, it's pretty arbitrary when Intellij matches from the start vs any part.  Annoying.

Comment: Oh, wait, the quotes are part of the regex.

Comment: The dot matches a double quote - don't use the dot. What you want is anything that is not a double quote, thus: `"[^"]*Model"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Misunderstanding about Shortest Match

In the context of lazy matching, the "shortest match" is the shortest match available to the lazy quantifier within the current match attempt.

The engine attempts its first match at the first position in the string. From there, it tries to match the pattern `.*?Model`. Is a match available at this position? Yes. The shortest match, from this position, is the entire string.

If you want to only match `FooModel`, you could for instance do `\w+Model`, or `[a-zA-Z]+Model`

Comment: OK, so how do I get what I want?

Comment: If you just want `FooModel`, you could do `\w+Model`

Comment: I normally do something like "[^"]*Model"

Comment: @enrico.bacis That would match `my dog and my Model`

Comment: @zx81 the OP didn't say anything about spaces and that's the most similar to .*?

Comment: @enrico.bacis Not an attack, just something worth noticing. You're right that tieTYT said nothing about spaces, but he said nothing about specifically needing to match within double quotes either. My understanding of the question was more `Why is this not working?`

Answer (score 3):

The `.*?` is lazy, but the regex engine starts the search greedily - that is, it tries to match at the start of the string, then the next position only if that fails, then the next position, and so on. Since the match succeeds at the start of the string, it never tries later positions.

You need to exclude quotes from the `.`:

```
"[^"]*Model"
```

This is slightly more complicated if you want to allow escape sequences like `\"`:

```
"(?:[^"]|\\.)*Model"
```

Answer (score 3):

Your regex indeed matches the whole String, because the first match is the leading quote.

Try this:

```
 (?<=")[^"]*Model(?=")
```

The negated character class for "not a quote" prevents the match from including a quote (and means you don't need the reluctant quantifier "?"). The look arounds are non-capturing, so the whole match is your target.

Comment: Learn about look arounds and lots more [here](http://regular-expressions.com/refadv.html)